# Segment Timestamps in pocketsphinx

Tags: speech-recognition, cmusphinx

I am trying to extract the start and end timestamps of each segment using pocketsphinx. The code below works for extracting the word token. How can I access the timestamps?

I've tried looking at the documentation here http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/doc/pocketsphinx/index.html but could not find the method

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os

import sphinxbase as sb
import pocketsphinx as ps

MODELDIR = 'deps/pocketsphinx/model'
DATADIR = 'deps/pocketsphinx/test/data'

# Create a decoder with certain model
config = ps.Decoder.default_config()
config.set_string('-hmm', os.path.join(MODELDIR, 'en-us/en-us'))
config.set_string('-lm', os.path.join(MODELDIR, 'en-us/en-us.lm.bin'))
config.set_string('-dict', os.path.join(MODELDIR, 'en-us/cmudict-en-us.dict'))
decoder = ps.Decoder(config)

# Decode streaming data.
decoder.start_utt()
stream = open(os.path.join(DATADIR, 'goforward.raw'), 'rb')
while True:
    buf = stream.read(1024)
    if buf:
        decoder.process_raw(buf, False, False)
    else:
        break
decoder.end_utt()
stream.close()
print('Best hypothesis segments:', [seg.word for seg in decoder.seg()])
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can explore segment in ipython

```
 print('Best hypothesis segments:', [(seg.word, seg.start_frame, seg.end_frame) for seg in decoder.seg()])
```

Frame size is 1/100 second.

Comment: Great, thank you. Is the time from end_frame_i to start_frame_i+1 always 1 frame? What if there is a long pause between segments?

Comment: For continuous speech you need continuous processing  like in https://github.com/cmusphinx/pocketsphinx/blob/master/swig/python/test/continuous_test.py Times will be reported properly from the start of the stream. Silence periods will be empty.

Comment: Ok, thanks. And using that, how would I access the time stamps? Sorry, I'm having trouble with the documentation

Comment: When I run that code, I get `RuntimeError: new_Decoder returned -1`

Comment: Most likely decoder wasn't able to load the model because you specified the wrong path to the model in sources. You can comment out logfn line to see more detailed log messages.