# Is there a way to return entire dictionary entry (word + phoneme) in pocketsphinx python?

Tags: python, speech-recognition, text-to-speech, pocketsphinx

Here is my code:

```
#!/usr

/bin/env python
import os

import sphinxbase as sb
import pocketsphinx as ps

MODELDIR = 'deps/pocketsphinx/model'
DATADIR = 'deps/pocketsphinx/test/data'

# Create a decoder with certain model
config = ps.Decoder.default_config()
config.set_string('-hmm', os.path.join(MODELDIR, 'en-us/en-us'))
config.set_string('-lm', os.path.join(MODELDIR, 'en-us/en-us.lm.bin'))
config.set_string('-dict', os.path.join(MODELDIR, 'en-us/cmudict-en-us.dict'))
decoder = ps.Decoder(config)

# Decode streaming data.
decoder.start_utt()
stream = open(os.path.join(DATADIR, 'hello_world.wav'), 'rb')
while True:
    buf = stream.read(1024)
    if buf:
        decoder.process_raw(buf, False, False)
    else:
        break
decoder.end_utt()
stream.close()
print('Best hypothesis segments:', [seg.word for seg in decoder.seg()])
```

Which I found in [this stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37973541/segment-timestamps-in-pocketsphinx)

The audio file hello_world.wav correctly outputs:  'Best hypothesis segments: hello world'

Here's my question. I'm looking in the pronunciation-dictionary.dict file located in: /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/speech_recognition/pocketsphinx-data/en-US, where it seems to be mapping english words to phonemes.

The entries for 'hello' and 'world' are:

```
hello HH AH L OW 
world W ER L D
```

I would like to return the entire line from the dictionary. So, rather than just 'hello', I would like 'hello HH AH L OW'. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: I don't think that audio file exists anymore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can lookup the pronunciation of the word once you get the results:

```
 print ('Best hypothesis segments: ', [(seg.word, decoder.lookup_word(seg.word)) for seg in decoder.seg()])
```

Comment: YES! Thank you! Perfect! This is exactly what I was looking for!